# Adding pd.series of minutes/seconds to a fixed datetime pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a fixed single datetime (datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 5, 16, 40, 19)
) and a pd series of increasing %H:%M:%S. The pd series is attached to no date and just represents various quantities of time. I want the series to be the fixed date + the amount of time. So, if the pd series is:

```
00:01:21
00:01:23
00:01:25
00:01:30
```

I want the first entry of the series to be 1 minute and 21 seconds after february 5th, 4:40:19 pm, the second 1 minute and 23 seconds after, etc etc

What is a good pandas/pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Instead of the most pandas way of doing it, have you implemented anything yourself? What happened, errors?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your series is in text format because you don't specify. If it is, in fact already in a timedelta, you don't need the first step.

```
# Create some test data
my_series = pd.Series(['00:01:21',
                '00:01:23',
                '00:01:25',
                '00:01:30'])

# Create series of time deltas
my_delta = pd.to_timedelta(my_series)
```

Now you can create a new series of dates from your original data

```
 # Create variable with the date to add
 my_date = datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 5, 16, 40, 19)

 # Add the two together
 result = my_date + my_delta
```